# Accumulator level on my ubuntu-touch tablet in command line

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-touch, tablet, m10

How could I know the accumulator level on my Ubuntu-touch tablet with cli? Tools like acpi or acpitool are not accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way! The question is solved:

```
cat /sys/devices/platform/battery/power_supply/battery/capacity
```

Comment: If this solves your problem please accept the answer by clicking on the check-mark. This will help other users in the future.